# Create a Cloudfront Distribution that Origin is an S3 bucket using ansible playbook

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ansible

I am using Ansible Playbook to push to an S3 bucket, and then use Cloudfront distribution to serve the site over https.

I would like to implement this using Ansible Playbook, however I haven't been able to configure the task correctly.  I'm not sure where to specify the S3 Origin of the bucket?

```
- cloudfront_distribution:
  comment: 'description'
  enabled: yes
  state: present
  default_root_object: index.html
  validate_certs: yes
  viewer_certificate:
    acm_certificate_arn: {arn of certificate}
  alias: {www.mydomain.com}
  origins:
    - id: 'id'
      s3_origin_access_identity_enabled: yes
```

Where can I specific the S3 bucket that I would like to serve through Cloudfront?

I've tried using the `origins` to specify the URL of the S3 bucket. But so far I have only been getting errors.

Would anyone be able to help me to specifiy the S3 bucket location so that I can serve the site through S3?

Comment: I had to set `s3_origin_access_identity_enabled` to `no` to get my s3 bucket data accessible via my cloudfront distribution. I don't think ansible created those policies automatically, but in the UI the option is there to create them.. either way it does work well without the restriction, but yeah the restriction is not applied in the case.

Answer (score 0):

It [appears](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.6.7/lib/ansible/modules/cloud/amazon/cloudfront_distribution.py#L1444) that the module is expecting `domain_name:` to be of the form `my-awesome-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com` which triggers the magic s3 sauce, and that should cause your `s3_origin_access_identity_enabled: yes` to take effect.

If you find that to be the case, it might be worth filing [an issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues) to have them update the documentation to be a little clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have removed 'alias' and have       `origins: - s3_origin_access_identity_enabled: yes domain_name: my-awesome-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
          id: 'S3-my-awesome-bucket'`
However, I am seeing the error: `Error creating distribution: An error occurred (InternalError) when calling the CreateDistribution operation (reached max retries: 4)`

Comment: So, just for clarity, I hope you didn't really use `my-awesome-bucket`, that was just an example. As for the `InternalError`, only running ansible at higher verbosity has a chance to surface what went wrong -- I have no idea